# A woman accepts being transplanted into a younger body

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

It is a futuristic movie.
There's a woman who lives with her daughter. An asian woman.
She has a well payed job. She's the image of the company. But because of her age (about 35) they need to change the image, so she suddenly got unemployed.
She can't find a job. I think she got a few bucks as "egg donor".

All what worried her was her daughter. She made an offer to the company she worked for. She would accept her consciousness to be transplanted to a younger body so the company could keep her experience and she kept the job. Somebody asked her not to do that. It seemed that the process had some side effects not well known.

She explained everything to her daughter and let her daughter choose the host young body, showing her several pictures, and warned her daughter to help her mother to remember once the transplantation took place.

The transplantation was made. The new mom went to live with her daughter. She seemed not to remember her daughter or anything about her personal life. But her job was fine. She needed some medicine injected into the stomach regularly.

The mother seemed not to recover her memories and she didn't feel anything for her daughter. About her daughter, she told a male friend from the company: "she hates me. and I don't care. We need a break from each other" and the friend yelled to her "AND WHAT WAS THIS ALL ABOUT?!"

I don't remember anything else. I think it is a recent movie. Probably after 2010.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Advantageous (2015)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advantageous)
[image]

> > Set in the near future, Gwen sells cosmetic procedures for the Center For Advanced Health And Living. Despite her relatively affluent
> >     position in life she works below scale and is having difficulty
> >     sustaining a lifestyle that will ensure her daughter, Jules, has a
> >     solid education and future. When she is abruptly fired from her job,
> >     Gwen's optimism quickly dissolves as she realizes the only offer she
> >     has for employment is as an egg donor, as women are rapidly becoming
> >     infertile. The firing comes at a critical juncture in Gwen's life
> >     because she needs money to ensure Jules's position at an elite school.
>
> Desperate, Gwen reaches out to her old employers, asking Fisher to use
>   her as one of the first subjects to transfer her consciousness into a
>   new body, allowing her to keep her old job by becoming more youthful
>   and racially ambiguous. Fisher assures her that if she agrees to the
>   body transfer the Center will do everything they can to ensure Jules's
>   future and protect Gwen as the face of the company. He also warns her
>   the procedure is in its infancy; for a year, Gwen will have to take
>   shots to help her breathe every two hours and will face enduring pain.
>   He explains the technology is not finished yet and begs her to
>   reconsider.
>
> Before agreeing to the procedure, Gwen tries one last desperate
>   measure. She reaches out to her cousin Lily and Lily's husband Han for
>   help. Gwen and Han had an affair years ago, and, though Lily is
>   forgiving of the affair, her attitude changes once she learns Gwen has
>   a child fathered by Han. She tells Gwen they need more time to think
>   about helping her, especially considering the suddenness of the news,
>   but Gwen tells her she has no time. Lily says she and her husband
>   cannot spare the money, as they have children of their own.
>
> Gwen breaks the news of her procedure to Jules, who seems
>   understanding. Together, they go to see Gwen's future body. After
>   Christmas, Gwen completes the procedure and returns home in a new
>   body, Gwen 2.0. Though she is disoriented and in pain, she does her
>   work for the center well. Jules, warned that her mother might be
>   slightly different, takes care of her and administers her shots when
>   she has difficulty breathing. However, Gwen 2.0 has trouble
>   understanding and relating to Jules after the procedure. She tells
>   Fisher she wants to separate from Jules, thinking Jules can take care
>   of herself and she needs the time alone. Fisher is furious and reveals
>   to Gwen 2.0 that she is not actually Gwen, but a twin that was
>   implanted with Gwen's memories; he explains the twin process to her
>   because he thinks it will be easier for the twin Gwen to merge with
>   the donor's memories if she does not know. Gwen's original
>   consciousness died during the procedure, but she was willing to go
>   through with it to ensure her daughter's future. Gwen 2.0 is
>   unaffected by the news and tells Fisher the part of Gwen that loved
>   Jules did not transfer. When she returns home, she tells Jules that
>   her mother is dead. Jules initially hides the shot Gwen 2.0 needs to
>   breathe but finally gives it to her. When she tells Gwen 2.0 she is
>   not sure why she is alive, Gwen 2.0 reassures her that her kindness is
>   unique to her. Jules tells her she sounds like her mother.
>
> Gwen 2.0 sees a message from Lily and Han where they apologize for
>   their initial dismissal and tell her that they want to help her and
>   Jules. Gwen 2.0 goes to their home and breaks the news about Gwen to
>   them. Later she organizes a picnic where Jules can meet Han, Lily and
>   their boys for the first time.

Comment: Thanks, pori. Now I can see the ending part which I think I missed for some reason.